# Volume is not showing even after implementing policy on EC2 and Volume

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-ebs

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:Describe*",
                "cloudwatch:Get*",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumes"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have defined above policy , able to see ec2 instances but not able to see volumes. It's showing message like:

> An error occurred fetching Volume information

Answer (score 0):

Requests made by the web console don't have a one-to-one mapping to the actual EC2 actions. Instead, they are proxied through some AWS internal APIs that don't have public documentations. Therefore, I would recommend using `ec2:Describe*` and save your a some time. If you really want to spend the time tweaking it and set the least privilege, you can either open a support ticket or try every `ec2:Describe*` action. Do note that since this is not documented publicly, this is not future-proof. In other words, if AWS decides to change the UI again in the future, your current permission setting may not work.